# Probability and Limits of Cumulative Distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, integers, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X : \Omega : \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a random variable defined over some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. The cumulative distribution function of $X$ is the function $F_X \colon \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ where $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

I wanted to show that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}F(k)=1$ where $k$ takes only integer

I would appreciate it if someone would get me started on this.

Comment: No, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} F_X(k) = \infty$ for all random variables $X$, simply because $F_X(k)\rightarrow 1$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Michael thank you so much! I have updated the question, which is simply asking (what you have mentioned) how can I show that $F_{X}(k) \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: This is something that you can only prove from the countable additivity axiom of probability, equivalently, from the fact of “continuity of probability.”

Comment: Actually, $F(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. This is stronger than saying that the limit through integers is $1$.

Comment: @Michael I appreciate your deep understanding to this! Would you please get me started using  countable additivity of disjoint pairwise

Comment: You can define $A_0= \{-\infty<X\leq 0\}$ and $A_n = \{n-1<X\leq n\}$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, so that $\{A_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a partition of the sample space into disjoint sets.

Comment: So, I should be looking at $P(- \infty < X\leq 0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(n-1 < X \leq n )$?